# How to convert a image in to different sizes

Tags: java, image

How do I resize a .jpg file using Java?  For example, I'd like to double the width and height of an image.

Comment: Check out the Image API. There is a method that will allow you to scale the image.

Comment: You could look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876615/how-do-i-resize-images-inside-an-application-when-the-application-window-is-resi/12876799#12876799) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) as just a few examples, and many more on SO if you did a quick search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `getScaledInstance` from `Image`. For more information see the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: `getScaledInstance` isn't necessarily the best choice, check out [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)