# how to create jframe with re sizable components

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a java application.there I want to keep jframe in maximized state.and I want to use it many of monitors that have different screen size.and I want to components in jframe to resize with jframe.also I need to add image to the background of the frame.that image also should resize with the jframe. how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Layout managers, layout managers, layout managers

Start by taking a look at

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [How to Use Various Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

You might also want to have a look at [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/), depending on what you're hoping to achieve

> also I need to add image to the background of the frame.that image also should resize with the jframe. how to do that?

- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [How to set a background picture in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430)
- [How do I resize images inside an application when the application window is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876615/how-do-i-resize-images-inside-an-application-when-the-application-window-is-resi/12876799#12876799)

I see lots of searching and research in your future.

Comment: Using Layout managers I can do some features.but I couldn't add image to the background. because, I had to set layout to null for add jlabel to the main panel.

Comment: *"because, I had to set layout to null for add jlabel to the main panel"* - Then you're doing it wrong - And I wouldn't use a `JLabel` for displaying a background image, one of the links above explains why.  If you don't want to use a layout manager, then you'll be re-inventing the wheel making your own, which will never work as well as those that are designed to work with the overall Swing API

Comment: yes,You are correct.but the matter is I'm fresher to java and I don't have much time to do this. So. I'm very complicated with this.However,I will have to find this.Thank you very much for your help friend.